# "HTTP Call" action in SharePoint 2013 Workflows fails when using Bearer tokens with period

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I've run into an interesting problem, and curious to know if anyone has experienced the same.

We're running SharePoint Server 2019 on-premise. Within SharePoint, we have workflows that call external APIs protected using OAuth Introspection.

I suddenly noticed that our workflows started failing. The situation got so bad that eventually, the WFM service started crashing altogether. The culprit was these XML exceptions that were being thrown as soon as the workflow reached a `Http Call` action, calling any OAuth-protected API resource. The symptom in WFM was that the workflow would get stuck on a step, then the following message would show in Windows Event Viewer on the SharePoint Server, before the WFM service would eventually crash:

```
Dispatcher encountered an unexpected exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.FormatException: The input source is not correctly formatted. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character 'x'.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.MoveToRootNode(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(Stream jsonStream, Byte[] jsonBytes)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.JsonWebToken.TryDeserialize(String jsonString, JsonObject& jsonObject)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.JsonWebToken.TryParseInternal(String rawToken, JsonWebToken& token, String& errorMessage)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HttpMessageSender.SendMessageAsyncResult..ctor(HttpMessageSender httpMessageSender, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, String scopePath, S2STokenCacheBackingStore cachedTokens, EventTraceActivity traceId, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.HttpRequestWorkItemAsyncResult..ctor(HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, HttpMessageSender httpMessageSender, String scopePath, S2STokenCacheBackingStore tokenCache, EventTraceActivity traceId, String sessionId, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnBeginComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.BeginComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.UpdateNonTransactionalWork()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.UpdateNonTransactionalWork()
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion callback, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(IAsyncResult result)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.FormatException: The input source is not correctly formatted. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered unexpected character 'x'.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlException exception)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.MoveToRootNode(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(XmlDictionaryReader jsonReader)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Json.JXmlToJsonValueConverter.JXMLToJsonValue(Stream jsonStream, Byte[] jsonBytes)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.JsonWebToken.TryDeserialize(String jsonString, JsonObject& jsonObject)
   at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.JsonWebToken.TryParseInternal(String rawToken, JsonWebToken& token, String& errorMessage)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HttpMessageSender.SendMessageAsyncResult..ctor(HttpMessageSender httpMessageSender, HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, String scopePath, S2STokenCacheBackingStore cachedTokens, EventTraceActivity traceId, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.HttpRequestWorkItemAsyncResult..ctor(HttpRequestMessage httpRequest, HttpMessageSender httpMessageSender, String scopePath, S2STokenCacheBackingStore tokenCache, EventTraceActivity traceId, String sessionId, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnBeginComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.BeginComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.UpdateNonTransactionalWork()<---
```

After a 3-week stint with Microsoft Support (don't get me started - useless), we upgraded everything we could, including migrating to SharePoint Workflow Manager, none of which solved the problem.

For absolute clarity, it is obvious there is no issue with the API resource because the workflow would fail before sending the API request to the OAuth-protected API. We confirmed that because in the IIS logs, there was no evidence of the HTTP request from the SharePoint Workflow.

After digging a bit further, I found the Bearer Tokens issued from our IdP started including periods, whereas before, the bearer tokens were shorter and without periods (e.g. `MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3`). To be clear, the bearer tokens from our IdP follow the RFC 6750 standard. See a fictitious example below for the Bearer Tokens we're now receiving from our IdP:

```
Bearer qhzQEXQqB_Jf4jbf1YzsdzEx4stsez9AteTjIf_mlb4.HXkMMMlTVLKTRFkevFAykOZ64Qy1jzH55-ApD00fcwsG12NtsBBT6z3W-kPxXto9OtjhGyU1y_-RzPolXr3Yqg.M18xNzA4NjM1OTk1MxXw
```

It seems like whenever you create a workflow in SharePoint 2019 and pass a Bearer Token with a period, the workflow goes into a Suspended status and, eventually, crashes the SPWFM service. Below is how we're passing in the Bearer Token:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced anything like this? Do you know of a workaround to fix it?

Comment: in a dev environment, try hard coding the  bearer token. If it works (and I suspect it would) then the problem is in the logic that fetches `isv_access_token`.

Comment: I've done that exact test already. In my environment, whenever I pass an access_token with a period (even when hardcoded), the request fails with the Xml Exception.

Comment: that seems weird. JWTs have periods in them. If you paste the token into something like jwt.ms does anything weird come up? It might be worth a support ticket to the IdP to figure out why they changed it. Sorry, I'm out of options. good luck!

Comment: @DerekGusoff do you have an on-premise SharePoint environment you can use to reproduce the issue?